# Validation for "at least one phone number is required" in CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is the model file `vechile_enquiry.php`

```
<?php
    class VechileEnquiry  extends AppModel{
        var $name ='VechileEnquiry';
        var $validate = array('name' => array
                                            ('rule' => 'notEmpty',
                                            'message' => 'Please type name')
                            );
    }
?>
```

This is the view file `vechile.ctp`

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>false));
?>
```

At least one phone number is required:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('mobile_phone', array('label'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('work_phone', array('label'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('home_phone', array('label'=>false));
?>
```

Validation is working in the name field but I'm not getting how to implement validation in `mobile_phone`,
`work_phone`, `home_phone` for the condition that at least one phone number is required.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372996/at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-cakephp-validation) has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
    var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please type name'
    ),
    'mobile_phone' => array(
        'check_phone' => array(
            'rule' => array('hasPhone'),
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'At least one phone number is required.'
        )
    ),
    'work_phone' => array(
        'check_phone' => array(
            'rule' => array('hasPhone'),
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'At least one phone number is required.'
        )
    ),
    'home_phone' => array(
        'check_phone' => array(
            'rule' => array('hasPhone'),
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'At least one phone number is required.'
        )
    )
); 


function hasPhone($field){
    if(!empty($this->data[$this->name]['mobile_phone']) || !empty($this->data[$this->name]['work_phone']) || !empty($this->data[$this->name]['home_phone'])){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: after fill mobile_phone , it's giving msg other two(work_phone,home_phone), how to stop it(after fill one not show msg for other two) ......thanks

Comment: @William_Golden You might have problems unless you take out those `'required' => true` and `'allowEmpty' => false` parameters, the `hasPhone` rule for each field should be enough.